# How to increment each timestamp incrementally for each row of a table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, timestamp

Let's say I have this table (there is only 2 columns for simplicity)

```
id ; created
1  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
2  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
3  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
4  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
5  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
6  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
7  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
8  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
...
```

I want to add +1 second (or minute) to each timestamp "created" so my table will become

```
id ; created
1  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:15.111897"
2  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:16.111897"
3  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:17.111897"
4  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:18.111897"
5  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:19.111897"
6  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:20.111897"
7  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:21.111897"
8  ; "2018-08-18 18:46:22.111897"
...
```

The reason why the "created" values or all the same is because I just added the column to my table and now I want to be sure my entries will be sorted correctly based on the timestamp with the new entries I'll be adding later in my table.

Comment: It seems you can manipulate the id to add it as a number of seconds to the time part of the created filed.

Comment: @Juan I thought about that but there are some "holes" in the id sequence, I wanted a cleaner way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using the `id`?

```
update t
    set created  = created + (id - 1) * interval '1 second';
```

If the `id`s have gaps, you can use a `join`:

```
update t
    set created = created + (seqnum - 1) * interval '1 second'
    from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.id = t.id;
```